# Is it unconnected adjective when the verb with ending "-ed"?

Tags: relative-clauses, participial-adjectives

Hi I'm a beginner in English. I'm confused about the grammar in English.

This sentence is an explanation for the verb *implement* means from [Oxford learners dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/implement_1)

> to make something that has been officially decided start to happen or be used

**Q1:** In the sentence there is *decided* in it. I wonder about *decided* whether it is a passive form from of the infinitive verb *decide* or a new word typed adjective.

**Q2:** Is *start to happen or be used* same as *start to happen or start to be used*?

**Q3:** I know *that* is a relative clauses and it  seems to be used for *something*, but why doesn't leave out even is an object?

Comment: Welcome to ell. I think you need to edit the title. I didn't change it since I was not sure what you intended. *decided* is a part of the passive "has been decided". Also "That" is a relative pronoun not a relative clause.

Comment: As a learner I suggest that you do not ask multiple questions within a single post. That makes the answers become long. You can ask about different topics in different posts.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking in Q3.

Comment: The wording used in this "Learner's Dictionary" definition is terrible. You might want to consider the regular *[Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/implement)*, which defines *implement* as 'Put (a decision, plan, agreement, etc.) into effect'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**decided** is the past-participle there ("something that *has been decided*") and yes, it is a passive construction.

> We have decided the matter.
>
> The matter has been decided.

Q2. We have the option to omit the second infinitive marker, **to**.

> Don't just sit there. Start to tidy up or (to) wash the dishes.
>
> The phrase gained popularity. It began to appear on billboards and (to) be used in TV ads.

My own personal preference when writing is not to omit **to** with the second infinitive if one of the verbs is transitive and the other intransitive, or if the first is an active construction e.g. **to appear**  and the second is a passive construction  e.g. **to be used**, unless the two verbs are the same:

> The legal principle of acting in self-defense refers to a situation where a
>   person has to kill or be killed.